# How to upgrade from React ^0.14.8 & React-native ^0.24.1 to React 15.0.2 and React-native 0.26.3

Tags: ios, react-native

I have Xcode version 7.3.1 node version v4.4.6 and npm version 3.8.6

So right now my ios React Native app is building with no problems but I am trying to use a library: https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/MIGRATION.md

that requires React-native version 0.26.3

So I checked https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.26-stable/package.json and found that there is a stable version of React-native 0.26.3 and React 15.0.2

So I changed my dependencies on my project in package.json and removed my `node_modules` folder and reinstalled.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "15.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.26.3",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.8.3",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "redux": "^3.5.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0"
  }
```

However my app is no longer working and I keep getting this error on startup. How should I upgrade to React 15 correctly?

```
ld: warning: object file (/Users/appollo_liu/Documents/workspace/laybium_workspace/laybium/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRNSound.a(RNSound.o)) was built for newer iOS version (9.0) than being linked (7.0)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      -[RCTJavaScriptContext initWithJSContext:onThread:] in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
      -[RCTJavaScriptContext init] in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
      -[RCTJavaScriptContext invalidate] in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
      _RCTNSErrorFromJSError in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
      +[RCTJSCExecutor runRunLoopThread] in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
      -[RCTJSCExecutor init] in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
      -[RCTJSCExecutor context] in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/laybium.app/laybium normal x86_64
(1 failure)
Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/laybium.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=LaunchServicesError, code=0):
The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)
Launching org.reactjs.native.example.laybium
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain, code=4):
The operation couldn’t be completed. (FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 4.)
```

Comment: Did you look at [this guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html) at all? Have you run `react-native upgrade`? It's meant to update all the dependencies and files that ship with react native for the new version. You'll have to go in and manually correct any values the upgrade overwrites afterwards.

Comment: the upgrade isn't working to get to react native 0.26 I'm trying to go from 0.14 -> 0.26.3

Answer (score 0):

First update your react-native to the newer release and after that run this `react-native upgrade` in your project root.